# How to setup iPads to be shared by multiple users?

Tags: ipad, user-account, single-user

My school has iPads for use for students. Currently, each student has their own iPad, with their own password, and own files on it.

But I've seen other schools instead have laptops where students can log into any laptop (or desktop computer in the building), and use it. They just enter their unique username and password, and they see their own desktop settings and files. Only an Internet connection is required.

Is there a way to setup iPads to be used in the same manner?

Answer (score 7):

iPads, by their nature are single user devices. One could go on and on about why that is or is not a good thing. But the fact remains that currently iOS does not offer multiple logins, like you can get on any Windows PC, or any Macintosh.

Apple does offer [Apple School Manager](https://www.apple.com/education/it/) that may give you some or most of what you are looking for. Perhaps someone with actual familiarity with this program could chime in or provide a more complete answer, but that link should at least get you started.

Comment: Apple School Manager is indeed what you need, but it has some hefty hardware requirements and a steep learning curve.